# What material is used in the texture viewport shading mode?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, 3d-view

I am very satisfied with the way my object looks in texture mode:[image: My object in the texture viewport]

But I am not satisfied with the way my object renders or how it looks in material mode: [image: My object in the material viewpoint]

I would like my object to render more or less exactly how it looks in the texture viewport, so what sort of material should I use to imitate the default material blender uses for texture mode?

Comment: It is not about the material, it is about the render engine and lighting. OpenGL viewport doesn't is just a basic preview for reference, there is no specific material. If you want exactly that appearance just do an OpenGL viewport capture.

Comment: I didn't know about openGL rendering. Thank you.

However, I would like to get my object to look like this in an actual render since I will be using it with other objects. Any information on how to construct my material and environment to achieve the darkness and contrast seen in texture mode is appreciated

Comment: You can render your scene normally with all your other objects then overlay an OpenGL render of his single object over them through compositing